# pgfplots dateplot: automated labels on full hours?

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I have some data as a function of time. I plot it using `dateplot` from the `pgfplots` package. I would like to have x labels in hours and minutes. For every day, I would like to have an additional `DD.MM.YYYY` label. This entry should only appear once per day, so the tick labels don't get too cluttered. (see below for MWE with picture)

Question 1: Is there any way to automatically get an x tick label every three hours? Right now, I have to give a full list with all x tick labels.

Question 2: Can I somehow automate the additional date label?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[compat=1.5.1,
        date coordinates in=x,
        xticklabel={\hour:\minute},
        xticklabel style= {rotate=45,anchor=north east},
        xtick={
            {2010-06-22 9:00},
            {2010-06-22 12:00},
            {2010-06-22 15:00},
            {2010-06-22 18:00},
            {2010-06-22 21:00},
            {2010-06-23 00:00},
            {2010-06-23 03:00},
            {2010-06-23 06:00},
            {2010-06-23 09:00}
        },
        date ZERO=2010-06-22,
        xlabel=Date and time,
        xlabel shift=20pt,
        ylabel=Random stuff,
        xmin={2010-06-22 9:00},
        xmax ={2010-06-23 07:25},
        minor x tick num = 2,
        clip=false
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (2010-06-22 09:06:03,0.1)
            (2010-06-22 16:14:07,0.8)
            (2010-06-23 07:00:25,1)
        };
        \node[anchor=north] at (xticklabel cs:0.1) {22.06.2010};
        \node[anchor=north] at (xticklabel cs:0.75) {22.06.2010};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is mainly an answer for question 2: How to automate placement of the day labels:

you can use `extra x ticks` to simplify the generation of these labels: it would allow you to separate the desired positions from their appearance.

You could do so by adding the lines

```
    xlabel shift=10pt,
    extra x ticks={2010-06-22 9:00,2010-06-23},
    extra x tick style={
        xticklabel=\day.\month.\year,
        every x tick label/.style={anchor=north west,yshift=-35pt},
    },
```

Concerning your first question (how can I generate tick positions every 3 hours): there is currently no way to tune the tick label generation in the requested way (the standard way of pgfplots to use `1,2,...,5` does not work for dates as far as I know - at least not for datetime).

Comment: Thank you, this simplifies the daily markers quite a bit. About the first question: I tried just that (not really thinking it would work). Any plans to include that possibility in future versions?

Comment: There are currently no plans in this direction. But I can think about it.

Comment: +1 for more control over datetime tick generation, I need that too.